# worksheet change event stops working when a 2nd excel file is open

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to toggle cells from a blank box to a check mark in certain columns. Then if that cell is checked it will send mass emails. Everything works fine until i open another excel file that has a `worksheet_change` event in its code.

How can I...

A) Make this code work even if other excel spreadsheets are open?

or

B) Change the way I am doing check marks so I do not require a Worksheet change? (something thats as fast as selecting a cell and can be added to thousands of cells. I'm looking at you form control check box)

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
With Target

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim WholeRng As Range

    Set rng = Cells

    lastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(7), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    Set WholeRng = Range(Cells(6, "D"), Cells(lastRow, "F"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

     If .Column = 4 And (Target.Row >= 6 And Target.Row <= lastRow) Or _
        .Column = 5 And (Target.Row >= 6 And Target.Row <= lastRow) Or _
        .Column = 6 And (Target.Row >= 6 And Target.Row <= lastRow) Then
        On Error Resume Next

        If Asc(.Value) = 82 Then
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
            .Value = Chr(163)
        Else
            .Value = Chr(82)
        End If
    End If

End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not about event stops working only in your code you are referring incorectly objects.

Example: `Range(Cells(6, "D"), Cells(lastRow, "F"))`

This always refers to ActiveWorksheet (not indicated explicitly so implicitly ActiveWorkbook is used). Therefore it is taking data from different place you expected.

You schould correct your code adding inplicit reference in each such property i.e. `sht.Range(sht.Cells(6, "D"), sht.Cells(lastRow, "F"))` where sht is worksheet you need.

Of course sht should be passed as argument or retrieved from Range.
Same for `Rng = Cells` etc.

EDIT:

For clarification - code works well in 1 workbook, if another is opened then context is switched - ActiveWorkbook etc. are now reffering to newly opened Workbook, Worksheet etc.

And all properties implicitly taking context returns wrong values (taken from different source).